# unable to run the springboot jar from command line

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

My requirement is to build a spring boot jar in standalone tomcat executable.I am not able to run the jar from command line.

I am using gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.4.0.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {

        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

group = 'com.test'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}



dependencies {
    compile project(':testProject')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')

    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')


}
configurations {
    all*.exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
}
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'SpringAppApplication',
                   'Implementation-Version': version
    }

}
```

running `java -jar target/SpringAppApplication-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`
I get error Invalid or corrupt jarfile `SpringApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`
.Tried giving the complete path also.

Comment: Are you using the old Spring Boot version by intention?

Comment: With springboot latest version it works fine